# Results not displaying with $$SearchTemplateDefault and Auto Frame option

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a $$SearchTemplateDefault on which I have a $$ViewBody field.   The $$SearchTemplateDefault  has the Auto Frame option set to launch the $$SearchTemplateDefault  form in a frameset.

I can see the $$SearchTemplateDefault form being displayed inside the frame but no results are displayed.

If I disable the Auto Frame feature the results are displayed but of course they are not being displayed in the frame as desired.

How can I get my search results to display in a frameset?

Example search:
http://myserver.test.com/leg/Contacts.nsf/name?SearchView&Query=Bob

P.S. This is an older site due to be replaced and I do not want to out the effort into say an xPages site which would actually make this job fairly easy. ;)

Comment: Is there by any chance a hide-when property on the paragraph containing $$ViewBody?

Comment: try naming the (result) frame "mainFrame" (I remember a very old bug that the only solution was to hard code the frame name)